# How to run a foreground service without killing on every phone including chinese rom like oppo and vivo

Tags: android, alarmmanager, foreground-service

I know we have got many questions on that topic but I am asking it again since I tried everything but unable to do it on oppo phones I tested but other apps like unolo is able to do on the same.

```
What I have:
```

I have a foreground service with an alarm manager that is checking after every 15 mins that the service is running or not and restarts the service

```
What I tried:
```

I enabled autostart and whitelisted app for battery optimization but the service is killed.

```
What unolo is doing:
```

It shows two dialog boxes asking for the same permissions and the service is running continuously

```
What I got:
```

My service is killed after swiping the app from recent tasks but unolo is running

Comment: i am not sure the android version the project targets, but >=28 a FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission and a notification are required. You may take a look at this if this is the case. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: though the chinese OEM OS have a problem on killing service is well known. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122098785

Comment: I have a proper working foreground service with notification on other phones. It kills only on oppo

Comment: @Shashank when it get killed, did `onDestroy` triggered?

Comment: @Ticherhaz no onDestroy and onTaskRemoved both are not called